# Is there any difference between `from abc import a,b` and `from abc import (a,b)`?

Tags: python, import

I encountered `from module_abc import (a, b)` when reading code. I would like to know if that's equivalent to `from module_abc import a,b`? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always thought that it is the same, i am using first option in case i have to move to the next row(e.g. too many classes to import)

```
from moduleA import (ClassA, ClassB, ClassC,
                     DataA, DataB)
```

Answer (score 3):

They're identical:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def a():
...     from module_abc import (a, b)
...     
>>> def b():
...     from module_abc import a, b
...     
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('a', 'b'))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module_abc)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (a)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             15 IMPORT_FROM              2 (b)
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('a', 'b'))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (module_abc)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (a)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             15 IMPORT_FROM              2 (b)
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Quite interesting: `from module_abc import a as a, b as b` yields exactly the same opcode.